# this in onclick with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 25 buttons like this:

```
<button class="Bouton_Clavier" onclick="Click_Bouton('Bouton-Name')"> 
  Bouton-Name</button>
```

I want to change button style when i click on (only fort the clicked button).

So, the function is :

```
function Click_Bouton(Nom) 
{
  $(this).removeClass('Bouton_Clavier').addClass('Bouton_Clavier_Select');
}
```

But it doesn't work.

If I change the function with :

```
function Click_Bouton(Nom) 
{
  $('button').click(function(){ $('button').removeClass('Bouton_Clavier')
    .addClass('Bouton_Clavier_Select'); 
  });
}
```

All buttons style are changed and its work after 2 clicks.

But I need to change only the style of clicked button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `this` is not set to what you think it should be.

```
<button class="Bouton_Clavier" onclick="Click_Bouton.call(this, 'Bouton-Name')"> Bouton-Name </button>
```

Also, I feel obligated to recommend not using `onclick=`, and instead using `$.click`.

Oh, and you don't seem to be doing anything with your argument `Dom`.

Answer (score 3):

Either manually set a context as [Paul Draper did in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621168/603003) or (better) don't use inline event handlers:

```
$(".Bouton_Clavier").click(function () {
  $(this).removeClass('Bouton_Clavier').addClass('Bouton_Clavier_Select');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the button css after click event fired like this,

```
$(".Bouton_Clavier").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('Bouton_Clavier').addClass('Bouton_Clavier_Select');
});
```

And in the last part of your code you mention **$('button')** that points to all buttons within your document. And that's why all button styles are changed on button click.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/2ndQS/)